# How to access ui grid row data in expandable row template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to implement an expandable ui grid with customized expandable template. How can I access the row data in the template?

In the controller, I defined the grid options like this:

```
            scope.GridOptions =
            {
                data: customers,
                columnDefs:
                [
                    { name: "FirstName", field: "FirstName", width: 130 },
                    { name: "LastName", field: "LastName", width: 130 }
                ],
                expandableRowTemplate: 'CustomerDetails.html',
                expandableRowHeight: 150
            };
```

and the template is as below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        {{FirstName}} {{LastName}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, what problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the answer. In order to access row data I need to use row.entity in the template.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        {{row.entity.FirstName}} {{row.entity.LastName}}
    </div>
</div>
```